Trouble understanding special case of functor category
I'm reading Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra: Part 1 and am slightly confused by an example showing a special case of the functor category:

If $\mathcal{A}$ is the (small) category with $\operatorname{obj}(\mathcal{A})=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(1,2)=\{i\}$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(3,2)=\{j\}$, then a functor $F: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ sends
$$
1 \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} 2 \stackrel{j}{\longleftarrow} 3
$$
to the sequence
$$
A \rightarrow C \leftarrow B
$$
(note that $A$ and $B$ are fixed). A commutative diagram is just a natural transformation. Hence, the category that arose in the exercise is just the functor category $\mathcal{C}^{\mathcal{A}}$.

where 'the category that arose in the exercise' is the category $\mathcal{C'}$ defined as:

given a category $\mathcal{C}$ and given fixed objects $A, B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then $\mathcal{C'}$ objects are $(A \stackrel{a}{\longrightarrow} C \stackrel{b}{\longleftarrow} B)$, where $C \in \operatorname{obj}(\mathcal{C})$ and $a,b$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ and whose morphisms are $\theta$ making the following commute
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A@>a>> C@<b<<B\\
@VV1_A V@VV\theta V @VV1_B V \\
A@>>a'> C'@<<b'<B
\end{CD}$$

In the example, I interpret the line '$A$ and $B$ are fixed' to mean that for any functor between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{C}$, $1$ and $3$ are always sent to the same object in $\mathcal{C}$. If this is what it is saying, I'm not sure why this must be the case. All I can think of, is that it has something to do with $2$ being terminal in $\mathcal{A}$ but I'm not sure how that would force $A$ and $B$ to be fixed.
(Also as a side question, what is the name of the category $\mathcal{C'}$ (if it has one) as it is not mentioned in the book?)
Any help would be appreciated.

I disagree with the line that says $A$ and $B$ are fixed.  I'm not sure why he said that.  I suppose it could depend on what $\mathcal{C}$ was.

Also, you have some arrows backwards in your last diagram.

the arrows b and b' are backwards

Thank you for fixing the arrows and formatting.

I also don't get why the author said $A$ and $B$ were fixed, this is a full subcategory of the functor category but not the entire category. For example in the functor category you also have $C \to C \leftarrow C$. Otherwise your category can also be seen as the category of cocones over the functor $G:{0,1} \to \mathcal{C}$ that sends $0$ to $A$ and $1$ to $B$.
